# str::contains doesn't work when the supplied input is a string reference

Tags: string, rust

```
use std::collections::HashSet;

fn character_count(needles: &HashSet<char>, needle_type: &str, input: &str) -> i32 {
    for needle in needles {
        let mut needle_custom;

        if needle_type == "double" {
            needle_custom = needle.to_string() + &needle.to_string();
        } else {
            needle_custom = needle.to_string() + &needle.to_string() + &needle.to_string();
        }

        if input.contains(needle_custom) {
            println!("found needle {:?}", needle_custom);
        }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

```
error[E0277]: expected a `std::ops::FnMut<(char,)>` closure, found `std::string::String`
  --> src/lib.rs:13:18
   |
13 |         if input.contains(needle_custom) {
   |                  ^^^^^^^^ expected an `FnMut<(char,)>` closure, found `std::string::String`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::ops::FnMut<(char,)>` is not implemented for `std::string::String`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::str::pattern::Pattern<'_>` for `std::string::String`
```

The code works if I replace `needle_custom` with `"test"`.

Comment: Its kind of a bummer that the error message mentions `char` because it makes it harder to diagnose as a common `&str` vs `String` issue

Comment: In the future, you are encouraged to search for your exact error message. In many cases, this will directly lead you to existing questions and answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `contains` method will accept an `&str` or a `char` but not a `String`.

The `contains` method [is declared as](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.contains)

```
pub fn contains<'a, P>(&'a self, pat: P) -> bool 
where
    P: Pattern<'a>,
```

And if you look at the [implementors of `Pattern`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/pattern/trait.Pattern.html#implementors), you'll see its implemented for `char` and for `&str`.

This means that you need to pass a `&str` to `contains` instead of your owned `String`. Because `&String` coerces to `&str`, this is an easy change:

```
-- if input.contains(needle_custom) {

++ if input.contains(&needle_custom) {
```

[Here is your code with this small change](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=56cdc97a7332cfa034a8ed0ddffbca71) working in the Playground.